# Kinesis data analytics cannot use same stream twice for different destinations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm using `kinesis data analytics` to do real time analytics.

After a couple of operations in `SQL` I pump the results to a sql stream named "OUTPUT_STREAM".

Next I configured a destination that routes the "OUTPUT_STREAM" to a `kinesis data` stream.
Then I also want to route the data of the "OUTPUT_STREAM" to a second destination which is a `kinesis firehose` stream.

The problem is that at this time kinesis is telling me:

> An output with name OUTPUT_STREAM is either already used or specified more than
>   once, please choose a different output name kinesis analytics

I fixed this by creating a second in application SQL stream OUTPUT_STREAM_2 which is just a copy of my original OUTPUT_STREAM.

However, why can I not subscribe 2 destinations (Kinesis Data Stream and Kinesis firehose) to the same SQL OUTPUT_STREAM ?